# Increase field length in sequential file

Tags: oracle11g, cobol, mainframe

if you were to extend a field length in the sequential file, would you rather add a new field at the end of the record since increasing field length in the middle of the fixed record format cause issues?

Comment: Yes, easier to add a new field on the end.

Comment: I have some unused smaller fields in the middle but they are useless as I cant extend their length, since I need a bigger field I have to add it at the end. What are the consequences of this if I continue to add at the end for every new requirement ?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with both `mainframe` and `oracle11g`?

Answer (score 3):

The solution in this case is to *add* the field at the *end*.

---

#### The Future

You also need to **think**
about the **future**. You do not want to have to *recompile every program* that uses a 
file *each time* the copybook is changed. 
There are several solutions

- Add a **filler** at the end - disadvantage wastes space
- Use a **VB file** - VB files are less common and less transportable
- **File-Driver** : do all IO in the one program isolating the Programs from the file.

Adopting any of the options means:

- Only *programs* that use the *new* field need to be **recompiled**.
- When *implementing* changes to the file into production, the *program* that *creates* the file needs to go in **first**. *Programs* that use the *new field* can go in **days / weeks / months** latter. This can **simplify** implementations. A couple of small implementations are far simpler than the one enormous big bang implementation.
- On the mainframe it saves changing the JCL each time the file attributes change.

#### Add a filler at the end

Simply define the file as

```
 01 My-Copybook
    05 First-field                         Pic ...
       ....
    05 Last-field                          Pic ...
    05 Filler                              Pic X(60).
```

when it comes to add a new field, you use some of the filler at the end:

```
 01 My-Copybook
    05 First-field                         Pic ...
       ....
    05 Last-field                          Pic ...
    05 new-field                           pic X(10)
    05 Filler                              Pic X(50). *> reduced to 50
```

#### Use variable length Records

You could use a VB file like

```
 01 Largest-possible-record                Pic x(500).

 01 My-Copybook
    05 First-field                         Pic ...
       ....
    05 Last-field                          Pic ...
```

You can now expand your record upto 500 bytes.

#### Use a file driver

Use a module (File-Driver) to read / write the file. All application programs
would call the File-Driver to do the actual IO.

The application programs would havwe something like

```
 05 Large-Record                          Pic x(1000).
 05 My-Record   redefines Large-Record.
    10 First-field                        Pic ...
        ....
    10 Last-field                         Pic ...
```

A file driver can do more than just write the file, they can add / validate
Header / trailers or other file check records that application programs are not 
interested in.

Comment: I have some unused smaller fields in the middle but they are useless as I cant extend their length, since I need a bigger field I have to add it at the end. What are the consequences of this if I continue to add at the end for every new requirement ?

Comment: If you just add fields at the end for each change you have recompile and retest every program that uses the file. On the Mainfame you would also have  change the JCL each time. If you adopt the above options, you only need to recompile programs that access the new field. Adopting the above also means the program creating the file can be put into production before any of the programs that read the file.